# How to stop latex from starting a new page?

Tags: floats, page-breaking, booktabs, footer

I am writing a two-column style report, and the house style mandates that references be printed at the end under a bottom rule. And what happens is that this bibliography (containing a single reference) gets printed at a new page. A total waste. What I did is force column breaks, so I know that if I remove the figure in the last column, everything fits, but if I make the figure any smaller, LaTeX ignores my column break and the figure spills halfways of the bottom page.

So actually, I think this is two questions:

1. How to force a column break in LaTeX without using the `multicol` package?
2. How to stop LaTeX from making a page break?

This is my code:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn,secnumarabic,amssymb, nobibnotes, aps, prb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \heavyrulewidth=.08em
    \lightrulewidth=.05em
    \cmidrulewidth=.03em
    \belowrulesep=.65ex
    \belowbottomsep=0pt
    \aboverulesep=.4ex
    \abovetopsep=0pt
    \cmidrulesep=\doublerulesep
    \cmidrulekern=.5em
    \defaultaddspace=.5em
}
\begin{document}
    \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},labelformat={default},labelsep=period,name={Slika}}
    
    \title{Title}%
    %*****************************
    \author{name}%
    \email{email}
    \affiliation{institution}
    \date{\today}%
    %*****************************
    
    \begin{abstract} 

    \end{abstract}
    
    %*****************************
    \maketitle
    %***************************
    \section{title}
    lorem ipsem
    \newpage
    \subsection{title}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{helix.jpg}
        \caption{Ilustration}
        \label{helix}
    \end{figure}
    lorem ipsum
    \nopagebreak[4]
    \begin{thebibliography}{50}
        \bibitem{priprema}
        reference title 
    \end{thebibliography}
    \nopagebreak[4]
\end{document}
```

Here is an image of the issue:

[image: wasteful]

Comment: I also tried to make the table smaller by shortening the caption, but then latex also spills the figure above onto the previous column, ignoring my pagebreak.

Comment: Note also that this is the APS journal style.

Comment: Try `\enlargethispage{{len}` where `len` is the amount to lengthen the page.